# Reset react navigation stack history

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

**Update**

Changed to use `DrawerNavigator` as the *root* for now, but would still like to know if it's possible to use `StackNavigator` as root but behavior like `tabs`, or `drawers`.

---

Am using reactnavigation v5.

I have the following setup:

```
<RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={'SplashNavigator'}>
  <RootStack.Screen name={'SplashNavigator'} component={SplashStackNavigator} options={{headerShown: false}} />
  <RootStack.Screen name={'DrawerNavigator'} component={DrawerNavigator} />
</RootStack.Navigator>
```

From `SplashNavigator` I do a `navigation.navigate('DrawerNavigator', {screen:'Home'})`

However, the header has a back button that navigates back to the splash screen.
Is there a way to reset the history so it'll take the `DrawerNavigator` as the main navigator?

Have tried `StackActions.replace` in HomeScreen but somehow it doesn't recognise the screen.

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.dispatch(state => {
      console.log(state);
      return StackActions.replace('Home')
    });
  }, []);
  ...
```

```
ExceptionsManager.js:173 The action 'REPLACE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

Yet I do see the route in the state

```
  "routeNames": [
    "Home",
    "Promotions"
  ],
```

Have tried `CommonActions.reset()` too but it didn't change anything.

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.dispatch(state => {
      console.log(state);
      return CommonActions.reset({...state, key:null})
    });
```